# Efficient way to determine total time taking overlap into account

Tags: python, pandas, time, overlap, calculation

I am using pandas dataframe for the following:

I am trying to find the best way to determine the total time spent by a ship at a particular berth taking into account overlap in the duration of the visit.
Here is what the data looks like:

```
 IN                    OUT                        BERTH 
2015-01-14 13:57:00   2015-01-15 17:15:00         01
2015-01-14 14:30:00   2015-01-15 02:50:00         01
2015-01-14 14:30:00   2015-01-16 06:10:00         01
2015-01-25 02:15:00   2015-01-26 13:41:00         01
```

what exactly i want is to find out is the total time a particular berth was used. So looking at the data there are overlaps and so i cant simply add the times for each record.

looking at the above data we can see that the 2nd ship timing is completely within the first so the time recorded for that would be 0, and that the 3rd ship comes before the first but stays till after the 1st one leaves so here the time would be = (out of 3rd ship - in of 1st) and then we would move to the next one as there is no overlap there and simply add [out of 4 - in of 4] to the total time spent on berth 1, and continue this till the end producing a something like this :

```
BERTH   HOURS WORKED
  01    7.750
  02    10.275
  03    5.585
  08    31.980
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?  I would start by building a list of time intervals, and when you process a new interval check to see if it falls partially (or entirely) inside one of your existing intervals, and if so, modify the existing interval as necessary.

Comment: As of right now i have only tried a few for loops with a bunch of if statements, but it never seemed to catch all the situations. But i see what you are saying and i will be trying out the solution DYZ just gave. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution for one berth. I hope you can expand it to multiple berths.

Split the dataframe into arrivals and departures:

```
dfIN = df[['IN']]
dfOUT = df[['OUT']]
dfIN['direction'] = 1
dfOUT['diretcion'] = -1
```

As of now, IN and OUT are just timestamps:

```
dfIN.columns = ('TS', 'direction')
dfOUT.columns = ('TS', 'direction')
```

Combine the two parts into one tall sorted dataframe of traffic:

```
traffic = pd.concat([dfIN, dfOUT]).sort_values('TS')
#                   TS  direction
#0 2015-01-14 13:57:00          1
#1 2015-01-14 14:30:00          1
#2 2015-01-14 14:30:00          1
#1 2015-01-15 02:50:00         -1
#0 2015-01-15 17:15:00         -1
#2 2015-01-16 06:10:00         -1
#3 2015-01-25 02:15:00          1
#3 2015-01-26 13:41:00         -1
```

Calculate the number of ships at the berth, as they arrive and depart:

```
traffic['ships'] = traffic['direction'].cumsum()
```

Identify time periods when the berth is empty. Then calculate the sequence number of each "busy period."

```
traffic['empty'] = (traffic['ships'] == 0).shift().fillna(0).astype(int)
traffic['busy_id'] = traffic['empty'].cumsum()
#                   TS  direction  ships  empty busy_id
#0 2015-01-14 13:57:00          1      1      0       0
#1 2015-01-14 14:30:00          1      2      0       0
#2 2015-01-14 14:30:00          1      3      0       0
#1 2015-01-15 02:50:00         -1      2      0       0
#0 2015-01-15 17:15:00         -1      1      0       0
#2 2015-01-16 06:10:00         -1      0      0       0
#3 2015-01-25 02:15:00          1      1      1       1
#3 2015-01-26 13:41:00         -1      0      0       1
```

Calculate the start and end of each "busy period":

```
busy_data = traffic.groupby('busy_id')['TS'].agg([min, max])
#                      min                 max
#busy_id                                        
#0     2015-01-14 13:57:00 2015-01-16 06:10:00
#1     2015-01-25 02:15:00 2015-01-26 13:41:00
```

Calculate the total length of all "busy periods":

```
(busy_data['max'] - busy_data['min']).sum()
#Timedelta('3 days 03:39:00')
```

Comment: Thank you! i will be trying this solution soon. Will update once ive tried it.